# Best way to record drums with one Mic?

Tags: audio-recording

What would be the best way to position a microphone record drums with one microphone?

Though seemingly a ridiculous question, as one whos strapped for cash and doesn't want to use a drum machine, how would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short & realistic, if somewhat cynical, answer would be...

Do it like they did in the 50's - find a good-sounding room, keep moving the mic around the room until you get the best sound.

Without knowing the room [with one mic, the room is far more important than the mic], no-one's going to get a better answer.

Comment: And seriously, move it around a lot. First in a couple feet increments, then when it's fine, move it inch by inch to find the best spot.